# GTK 3.0 style stack pages with CSS

Tags: css, c, user-interface, gtk, gtk3

I am working on a GTK application using C. I've split the app into multiple Stack pages. Now I want to style them accordingly. I would like to assign one CSS file to one Stack page but using one single CSS would also do the job. My biggest problem is that I can't figure out how to style individually Widgets in CSS.

main.c

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
  
      gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
      GtkWidget *window;
      window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
      gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 280,800);
  
      GtkWidget *stack = gtk_stack_new();
      gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), stack);
 
      GtkWidget *page_start = create_page_start(window, stack);
      gtk_stack_add_named(GTK_STACK(stack), page_start, "page_start");
      GtkWidget *page_game = create_page_game(window, stack);
      gtk_stack_add_named(GTK_STACK(stack), page_game, "page_game");
  
      g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit),NULL);
      gtk_widget_show_all(window);
      gtk_main();
  
      return 0;
  }
```

page_start.c:

```
static void start_game(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data){
         GtkStack *stack = GTK_STACK(data);
         gtk_stack_set_visible_child_name(stack, "page_game");
}

GtkWidget *create_page_start(GtkWidget *window, GtkWidget *stack){
         GtkWidget *grid = gtk_grid_new();
         GtkWidget *label;
         GtkWidget *btn_start;
    
         GtkWidget *label = gtk_label_new("Label1");
         btn_start = gtk_button_new_with_label("Start");
         g_signal_connect(btn_start, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(start_game),stack);
         gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), label, 0, 0, 1,1);
         gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), btn_start, 0, 1,1,);
         return grid;
       }
```

I would like to have a page_start.css and a page_game.css for the two stack pages I have. In those CSS files I need to be able to get the label and btn_start for example.
Is using CSS even best practice? Are there other options?